# UCanAccess calling saved Append, Update, or Delete query

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I have an Append query object in my Access database. I can call all Select query objects, with no issues.

But if the query inserts into db, I can not call it from Java, the error is "lack of privileges or object not found".

How can I call the insert/append query from my Java code?

Answer (score 1):

UCanAccess can execute saved "action queries" in Access (Append queries, Update queries, and Delete queries) using a `CallableStatement` object.

If the saved query has no parameters then the code is simply

```java
try (CallableStatement s = conn.prepareCall("{call MyAppendQuery()}")) {
    s.execute();
}
```

(Note that the empty parentheses `()` after the query name are required.)

For a saved action query with parameters, the code is like this

```java
try (CallableStatement s = conn.prepareCall("{call MyAppendQuery(?,?)}")) {
    s.setString(1, "Hello from UCanAccess");
    s.setTimestamp(2, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2011-01-31 14:15:16"));
    s.execute();
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the respond. I have tried this before, but the append query it self contains more query objects, and I always get the error: UCAExc:::3.0.6 user lacks privilege or object not found. Thank you very much for you answer anyway.